# Can both $f(n) \neq O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \neq O(f(n))$ happen at once?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

For which case are both $f(n) \ne O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \ne O(f(n))$ true?

I have following answer to this which I could not understand:

> Sometimes true: For $f(n) = 1$ and $g(n) = |n \sin n|$ it is true, while for any $f(n) = O(g(n))$, e.g. $f(n) = g(n) = 1$, it is not true.

Please someone help in understanding:

- For which case is it sometimes true? An explanation with example will be much appreciated.
- What is meaning of "||" in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Comment: Here, || means absolute value. In the case of f(n) = 1 and g(n) = |n sin(n) |, we have neither f(n) = O(g(n)) nor g(n) = O(f(n)).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following statement about two functions $f,g$:

> $f(n) \neq O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \neq O(f(n))$.

The question wants you to choose which of the following holds:

- The statement holds for every $f,g$.
- The statement holds for no $f,g$.
- The statement holds for some $f,g$, and doesn't hold for other $f,g$.

The third option is correct in your case, and this is the meaning of "sometimes true".

Indeed, if $f(n) = g(n) = 1$ then the statement doesn't hold. Conversely, if $f(n) = 1$ and $g(n) = |n\sin n|$ (where $\left|\cdot\right|$ denotes absolute value) then the statement does hold.